# JavaScript with HTML DOM doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My JavaScript function `date(id)` is supposed to display the current date by accessing an element passed in the function call. The problem is it doesn't work and I can't understand why. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function date(id)
{
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>
```

in the HTML:

```
<p style = "text-align:center;" id = "datep">
</p>

<input type = "button" onclick = "date(datep)" value = "Display date" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your input tag you have the id passing to your function. Your id is a string and since it is you need to put quotes around it.

It should look like this...

```
<input type="button" onclick="date('datep')" value="Display date" />
```